# Cannot create React app as NPM is "unable to resolve dependency tree"

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am trying to create a React app. Below are the versions for Node & NPM:

```
C:\React>node -v
v15.2.0

C:\React>npm -v
7.0.8
```

When I run the command to create a React app, the following messages occur:

```
C:\React>npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in C:\React\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: @babel/core@7.12.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@babel/core
npm ERR!   @babel/core@"7.12.3" from react-scripts@4.0.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!     react-scripts@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   @babel/core@"^7.12.3" from @svgr/webpack@5.5.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@svgr/webpack
npm ERR!     @svgr/webpack@"5.5.0" from react-scripts@4.0.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!       react-scripts@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   9 more (babel-jest, babel-loader, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @babel/core@"^7.13.0" from @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.14.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining
npm ERR!   @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@"^7.14.5" from @babel/preset-env@7.15.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@babel/preset-env
npm ERR!     @babel/preset-env@"^7.12.1" from @svgr/webpack@5.5.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@svgr/webpack
npm ERR!       @svgr/webpack@"5.5.0" from react-scripts@4.0.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Comment: Use `--legacy-peer-deps` like the error message suggests. Blame it on NPM v7's broken handling of peer dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there is a mismatch in the peer dependencies. I resolved this issue earlier with:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Followed with:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```